# The action target is located outside the layout viewport testcafe

Tags: testcafe

I am using `testcafe` for web testing. The frontend application is written in reactjs with material ui design components.

Following is the code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction,  } from 'testcafe'; // first import testcafe selectors

fixture `Getting Started`// declare the fixture
    .page `https://webserver`;  // specify the start page


const newSearch = Selector('button').withText('Start a New Search');
//then create a test and place your code within it
test('My first test', async t => {
    await t.typeText('#signin-username', '<email>');
    await t.typeText('#signin-password', '<passwd>');
    await t.click('#okta-signin-submit');

    await t.debug();
    const newSearchElement = await newSearch.with({visibilityCheck: true})();
    await t.click(newSearchElement);
});
```

I am trying to click on a `button` having text Start a New Search but it throws an error saying

`The action target (<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedSuccess MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedSuccess MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium css-1d4ajd1" tabindex="0" type="button" style="margin-left: 3px;">...</button>) is located outside the layout viewport`

The button is visible and is at the top of webpage. The display property of button is `inline-flex`.

In error, the css of button is correct.
What change is required so that click on that button will work via `testcafe`?

To execute the test case I am running `testcafe edge tests.js`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find out the reason for the issue without an application. Please share a simple sample. Possibly, you have another element with the same selector, and it is really located outside the layout viewport but was placed earlier in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe will not be able to click on a button that is outside of the viewport. This is because TestCafe uses the browser's native event handling system to perform actions on the page. If the button is not visible in the viewport, the browser will not be able to dispatch an event to the button, and TestCafe will throw an error.

There are a few things you can do to work around this issue:

Scroll the button into view before clicking it. You can do this using the t.scroll() action.
Use a custom action to click the button. This will give you more control over how the button is clicked.
Change the CSS of the button so that it is always visible in the viewport. You can do this by setting the position property to fixed and the top and left properties to 0.
Here is an example of how to use each of these workarounds:

Scroll the button into view before clicking it:

```
test('My first test', async t => {
  // ...

  const newSearchElement = await newSearch.with({visibilityCheck: true})();
  await t.scroll(newSearchElement);
  await t.click(newSearchElement);
});
```

Use a custom action to click the button:

```
const clickButtonOutsideViewport = async (element: Selector) => {
  // Get the bounding box of the element.
  const boundingBox = await element.boundingBox();

  // Scroll to the element so that it is visible in the viewport.
  await t.scroll(boundingBox.x, boundingBox.y);

  // Click the element.
  await t.click(element);
};

test('My first test', async t => {
  // ...

  const newSearchElement = await newSearch.with({visibilityCheck: true})();
  await clickButtonOutsideViewport(newSearchElement);
});
```

Change the CSS of the button so that it is always visible in the viewport:

```
.new-search-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Once you have made one of these changes, you should be able to click on the button without any problems.

Additional tips
If you are using ReactJS and Material UI, you may also want to try the following:

Make sure that the button is rendered inside of a Container component. This will ensure that the button is always visible in the viewport, even if the page is scrolled.
Use the useMediaQuery hook to detect the viewport size and adjust the CSS of the button accordingly. For example, you could make the button smaller on smaller screens.
I hope this helps!